# "used force to arrest" vs. "used force in arresting"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I came across this sentence from a news article, saying "Police used force in arresting protesters." And I thought that this sentence should be like "Police used force to arrest protesters."

After a brief survey, I realized that both are grammatically correct. Could anyone tell me about the differences between "to arrest" and "in arresting"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The cited text isn't very idiomatic compared to *many* alternatives - including simply ***deleting the word "in"*** (there's nothing wrong with ***Police used force arresting protesters***, but most people would include ***when*** or ***while*** in such contexts). The difference between that continuous form and the infinitive *(**to arrest**)* is that using the latter implies they ***needed*** to use force to achieve their goal (arresting protesters), whereas the version *actually* used simply says that force *was* used (regardless of whether it made their job any easier or not).

Comment: The simple infinitive (and, indeed the simple form of all tenses) indicates a complete action from start to finish; the "-ing" form indicates (i) the **process** of the action a point or points within its duration and (ii) refers to an ongoing action that was not complete at the time referred to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, your comment seems to amount to an answer; why not post it as such?

Comment: @jsw29: Because I voted to migrate the Q to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -2):

You could always use the term “forcibly”
although I cannot think of a any situation where “force” is not involved in arresting someone; (except maybe when a message is left asking someone to “turn themselves in”.)